# Redirecionamentos com Htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, apache, cpanel

Gostaria de elaborar uma configuração htaccess que seja mais ou menos com as seguintes regras.

Ao acessar http://subdominio1.meusite.com.br/ direcione para uma pasta especifica e quando acessar http://*.meusite.com.br/ direcionasse para outra pasta qualquer do meu servidor.

Se eu seto um subdominio no cpanel o htaccess ignora e passa a seguir suas proprias regras, se eu seto o proprio htaccess para pegar *.meusite.com.br ele ignora o subdominio fixo...

Como resolver?

Comment: Está um pouco confuso sua pergunta, peço que edite a mesma e insira trechos do seu `.htaccess` para que possamos te ajudar melhor, e qual serviço de hospedagem está utilizando?